# How to get just the correct response from TComPort - Delphi?

Tags: delphi, at-command, tcomport

When i send the command "AT+CUSD=1,"*200#",15" i get the response:

```
OK


+CUSD: 0,"Crdit :1.33DA au 21/05/20.Credit offert :0DA",15
```

Is there a function or another AT command to get just

```
Crdit :1.33DA au 21/05/20.Credit offert :0DA
```

which is the the answer i want ?

Comment: I guess not. Just search for the position of `Crdit`, and copy the result from there.

Comment: `extractResultArr := StrUtils.SplitString(modemResponseStr,'"');` will give you the result in `extractResultArr[1]`.

Comment: @LURD thanx that helped but still there is a problem, when the response contains **"** it works fine but when the response do not contain **"** it shows **邀bˤc邀b邀b諰̠,**! for example when the response is **OK**, i found a solution but i don't know how to write it in code, i want to add an IF statement like that: `If the response contain " then do the treatment you gave me`   how can i do that in Delphi ? here is the RxChar function: `procedure 
var arr : TArray<String>;
s : String;
begin
CPOoredoo.ReadStr(str, Count);
arr := StrUtils.SplitString(str,'"');
memo1.Lines.Add(arr[1]);
end;`

Comment: `if Pos('"',str) > 0) then ...` will tell you if the `"` character is in the response.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what am searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modem response is string-package divided by commas.

You can:
- assign this string to `TStringList.DelimitedText` to get collection of individual substrings
- identify package by 0-th item - here `'CUSD'`
-  get 1-th item as `'Crdit...'`

Example with `Memo.Lines` (of type `TStrings`):

```
var
  s: string;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  s := '+CUSD: 0,"Crdit :1.33DA au 21/05/20.Credit offert :0DA",15';
  sl := TStringList.Create; 
  try
    sl.Delimiter := ',';
    sl.StrictDelimiter := True;
    sl.DelimitedText := s;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(sl[1]);
  finally
    sl.Free;

result in sl:
 +CUSD: 0
 Crdit :1.33DA au 21/05/20.Credit offert :0DA
 15
in Memo:
 Crdit :1.33DA au 21/05/20.Credit offert :0DA
```

Comment: DA stands for Algerian Dinars it is a Currency of a north African country (Algeria my country :)).

Comment: Thank you @MBo so much, your example code worked well but i couldn't do that solution in the **RxChar** event, that Delimiter thing is new to me, here is the RxChar function fix it to me please: `procedure TForm1.CPOoredooRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
begin
CPOoredoo.ReadStr(str, Count);
Memo1.Lines.Add(str);
end;`  also the result is 3 diffrent strings, i want to just show the second one which is **Crdit :1.33DA au 21/05/20.Credit offert :0DA**

Comment: Logic is simple: you have 3 strings and want to show only the second? - in this case don't show the first and the last.

Comment: The TStringList sl variable you added, added the logic to my head, thnx